# Detect angular configuration from angular.json in code

Tags: angular

I had more configuration on angular.json
How I can detect angular configuration from angular.json in code? It is need for specific logic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, the Angular.json is "compile time logic" and cannot be accessed at "run time".

For runtime configs I might put them in a JSON Document that is packaged with the app and loaded at runtime.

Or I may load them on demand from a REST service / database.

Or I may set up different environment files.